# Can I access feed (own posts) of a test user?

Tags: testing, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to write some tests for posting and commenting into facebook from my application. For this purpose I create two test users as described in the [official doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/) using my app secret. Then I try to create a post as the first user and leave a comment as the second user. While the first step succeeds on the second step I receive an error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Error finding the requested story","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

I also tried to access the created post in the following ways:

1. Directly by id, using `https://graph.facebook.com/<post id>` url, with access tokens from both users, my application and my personal fb account.
2. Looking on the first user's feed on `https://graph.facebook.com/<user id>/posts` url, also with every possible access token.

In every case I receive just 'false' in response. So I suppose that all posts from a test user are not persistent and can't be ever accessed. Am I right, or may be I'm doing something wrong? Is it possible to test posts and comments with test users, not real accounts?

I gave not a full view of how exactly test is written, but the graph API interaction is quite complex in this case and I can't say for sure what is relevant here. Feel free to ask for more info in comments.

**UPDATE** detailed reproduction

This is how I obtain application access token:

```
$ curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<app_id>&client_secret=<app_secret>&grant_type=client_credentials'
access_token=<app_token>
```

And create test user:

```
$ curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/<app_id>/accounts/test-users?installed=true&permissions=publish_stream&method=post&access_token=<app_token>'
{"id":"100003312676861","access_token":"<user1_token>","login_url":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/platform\/test_account_login.php?user_id=100003312676861&n=mFdbI0ThjAcqEmR","email":"hrputis_fergiesen_1325848209\u0040tfbnw.net","password":"<user1_pass>"}
```

Then I'm trying to create a post and it succeeds:

```
curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/100003312676861/feed?message=hello&method=post&access_token=<user1_token>'
{"id":"100003312676861_107495629370859"}
```

But when I try to access the created post I can't do it with either application and user token:

```
curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/100003312676861_107495629370859?access_token=<user1_token>'
false

curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/100003312676861_107495629370859?access_token=<app_token>'
false
```

And it doesn't appear in the user's feed.

```
curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/100003312676861/feed?access_token=<user1_token>'
{"data":[]}

curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/100003312676861/feed?access_token=<app_token>'
{"data":[]}
```

**UPDATE2** Acces token details:

For the application token linter correctly recognizes ID and application name.

For the user token linter give me following information:

```
App ID: <correct app ID and name>
User ID: Unknown
Issued: 1326186000 : 1:00 am Jan 10 2012
Expires: 1326189600 : 2:00 am Jan 10 2012
Valid: True
Origin: Unknown
Scopes: create_note photo_upload publish_stream share_item status_update video_upload
```

Answer (score 0):

After logging in with the test user account, I went to the graph API explorer and grabbed an access token for them.  I then checked the `me/feed` and it was empty.  Just as expected because it is a new test user account.  I then did a post to the me/feed using the explorer, and the graph returned a id. Who hoo!  Then I went back to me/feed and that new post was listed.   When I take that user access token to the linter, it showed me that the token was for the test account user and the correct permissions were requested.  Can you check your user access tokens you've tried in the linter to ensure that the access_token is setup correctly?  Post your results here, please  :)

Comment: What does the linter say about your access tokens?

Comment: I've added token info from the linter. Sorry for the delay, I had no access to my workstation for a few days.

Comment: `User ID: Unknown`  That part is not correct.  You are using the wrong access token.

Comment: but it was given by the FB API. Where should I obtain the correct one?

Comment: Read http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/.  It shows a few ways to grab a user access token.

Comment: Don't know. Thank god we have stopped to integrate this mess into our application.

Comment: Could you please close your question so it doesn't show up on the open question list?  Thanks!